# Performing arithmetic on floating point values of different sizes

Tags: python, tkinter, floating-point, size, tkinter-entry

My code does not run as I would expect if one float variable has 5 digits, others have 4, and an arithmetical operation is performed on them. For example:

```
def capacity(self):

    mmax = self.mmax.get()
    current = self.current.get()
    mmin = self.mmin.get()

    flag = False

    if flag is False:
        if mmax.isdigit() and mmin.isdigit() and current.isdigit():
            capacity = float(100 * ((float(current) - float(mmin)) / (float(mmax) - float(mmin))))
            if mmin <= current <= mmax and 0 <= capacity <= 100:
                flag = True
            else:
                self.result = str("Please ensure the values entered correspond to the correct value.")
        else:
            self.result = str("Please enter only positive integers.")

    if flag is True:
        self.result = "Capacity: %2.2f" % capacity + '%'
```

If `mmax = 10000, current = 5000, and mmin = 1000`, `self.result = str("Please ensure...")`.
If `mmax = 9999, current = 5000, and mmin = 1000`, `self.result = str("Capacity: 44.45%)`.

What's going on here/ how can I overcome this problem?

Comment: That's a lot of `float`s... can you clarify what you were expecting? Also note that e.g. `if not flag:` is preferred to `if flag is False:`, as it deals better with false-y values that *aren't* `False`.

Comment: You should check the values are really those you expect, for `mmax`, `current` and `mmin`. If I just force them to be 10000, 5000 and 1000, it gives the correct result.

Comment: @spectras It was a matter of me getting `mmax`, `current`, and `mmin` from a tkinter entry which return strings and I was doing arithmetic directly on them before converting to a float/ integer. @jonrsharpe Duely noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that `mmin` and `current` and `mmax` are strings. In which case, this expression:

```
if mmin <= current <= mmax and 0 <= capacity <= 100:
```

... Is doing a lexicographical comparison on the values. This is different from a numerical comparison: for example, `"5000" < "10000"` evaluates to False because "5" is larger than "1".

Convert your values to numbers before doing comparisons on them.

```
if mmax.isdigit() and mmin.isdigit() and current.isdigit():
    mmax = float(mmax)
    current = float(current)
    mmin = float(mmin)

    capacity = float(100 * ... #etc
```

Or

```
if float(mmin) <= float(current) <= float(mmax) and 0 <= capacity <= 100:
```

Comment: We don't know for sure until you get asker's feedback, but given the symptoms, that seems to be an excellent catch with fix. +1-ing

Comment: The `tkinter` tag is an additional clue, because `get()` is most commonly a method of Tkinter Entry boxes, and it returns a string.

Comment: Also, calling `isdigit` would give a syntax error if they were numbers.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, which is why I had to edit out my first suggestion of wrapping `float` around the `get` calls.

Comment: @Kevin Yeah I was using `.get()` to localize tkinter entries within this fuction and I didn't know that tkinter entries always return strings. @saulspatz you're right. I had tried `mmax = float(self.mmax.get())` but the `isdigit` method only works on strings.